# More classes with same static functions with different functionality

Tags: c#, generics, static

I have several classes with different properties and I want to do the same thing with instances of these classes. Lets say save their properties to text file with another informations (I don't have all the informations in that instance so I can't use something like `ToString()` method - I have to work with those properties in another class).
Here are example of two classes:

```
class Dog
{
    public int Height { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class Car
{
    public bool IsConvertible { get; set; }
    public string VIN { get; set; }
}
```

In text file I want to have instances saved like:

20151023; Dog; 32 cm; My dog;
20151023; Car; true; WP0ZZZ99ZTS392124;

I thought that it would be nice to have special static class for every supported class with methods `public static void Write(T)` and `public static T Read(string line)`. Both methods have same name in every class but slightly different functionality so I thought that `Interface` or `Abstract class` could work, but neither works with `static` methods.

1. Is there some way how I can be sure that those static methods are implemented in all classes?
2. Is it better to use "classic" classes instead of `static` ones in this case?

Comment: Sounds like a job for serialization.

Comment: I don't see anything in your classes marked `static`, where are you getting this static information from?

Comment: @SteveFenton It is some kind of serialization but I have to "serialize" these objects to different program which has strict rules for incoming data and I am not able to achieve that rules with XML/binary serialization.

Comment: @RonBeyer There are no static informations in these classes. I just thought that creating static helper class for working with these classes is better than creating instance of helper class every time I want to save/load something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that you are looking for an approach that allows you to define some abstraction that can be implemented for different classes. And that saving object content to some string is just an example of that. If this is not the case (i.e. you only care about serialization), then simply use the serialization API from the .NET framework.

> Is there some way how I can be sure that those static methods are implemented in all classes?

You cannot do this with C# alone. You can use some tools that hook into the compilation process and allow you to set custom rules for your classes. I don't recommend you do this in this case though.

> Is it better to use "classic" classes instead of static ones in this case?

Yes. I suggest that you create an generic interface.

I will use the same example (saving content or Serialization) that you provided:

```
public interface ISerializer<T>
{
    string Read(T obj);
    void Write(T obj, string data);
}
```

And then you can create serializers for the objects. Here is an example for the `Dog` object:

```
public class DogSerializer : ISerializer<Dog>
{
    public void Write(Dog obj, string data)
    {
        //Parse the data string and set properties on the object
    }

    public string Read(Dog obj)
    {
        //Create a string by reading properties from the dog object
    }
}
```

You can also create a generic serializer that uses [Reflection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183.aspx) to read/write properties from/to any object.

```
public class Serializer<T> : ISerializer<T>
{
    public string Read(T obj)
    {
        //Use reflection here to read object properties
    }

    public void Write(T obj, string data)
    {
        //Use reflection here to set object properties
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can not use serialization API and I agree that use those tools for compilation tests is not the right thing for my problem so I probably end up with some `Interface` and helper class instances as you also suggests. And thank you that you remind me `Reflection` ;-)